# UNIX Shell Script Solution for formatting a pipe-delimited, segmented file

Tags: unix, awk, grep, sql-loader

The input file has up to 34 different record types within the same line.

The file is pipe-delimited, and each record type is separated by '~' (except for the originating record type.

Not all 34 record types are contained on each line, and I do not need all of them.

All record types will be sent within a specified order, but not all record types will always be sent.  The first record type is mandatory and will always be sent.  Out of the 34 types, there are only 7 that are mandatory.

Each record type has a predefined number of fields and that should never deviate from that definition without proper lead time between the client and our load.

The Oracle table will be constructed with all of the required columns based upon the needed record types.  So one row will contain information from each record type similar to the input file, but will additionally include nulls for the columns which would come from certain record types that were not included in the input.

The end result I'm looking for is a way to perform conditional formatting to the input file in order to generate an output that can be simply loaded within a shell script via sqlldr instead of going through PL/SQL (as I want my non-PL/SQL coworkers to be able to troubleshoot/fix any issues encountered during loads).

Small example with 3 records (data types do not matter in this example):

```
Record Types:  AA, BB, CC, DD, EE, FF  
AA has 5 fields (Mandatory)  
BB has 2 fields (Optional)  
CC has 3 fields (Optional)  
DD has 6 fields (Optional)  
EE has 4 fields (Optional)  
FF has 2 fields (Not needed.  Skipping in output)  
GG has 4 fields (Optional)


AA|12345|ABCDE|67890|FGHIJ|~BB|12345|~CC|ABCDE|12345|~DD|A|B|C|D|E|~EE|1|2|3|~FF|P|~GG|F|R|T
AA|23456|BCDEF|78901|GHIJK|~CC|BCDEF|23456|~EE|2|3|4|~GG|R|F|G
AA|34567|CDEFG|89012|HIJKL|~DD|B|C|D||~FF|Q
```

Line 1 has no issues because it has all available record types, but lines 2 and 3 do not.  So they would need to be modified to include the missing record types.  The overall output would need to look something like this:

```
AA|12345|ABCDE|67890|FGHIJ|~BB|12345|~CC|ABCDE|12345|~DD|A|B|C|D|E|~EE|1|2|3|~GG|F|R|T
AA|23456|BCDEF|78901|GHIJK|~BB||~CC|BCDEF|23456|~DD||||||~EE|2|3|4|~GG|R|F|G
AA|34567|CDEFG|89012|HIJKL|~BB||~CC|||~DD|B|C|D||~EE||||~GG|||
```

I have started by taking each record, splitting it into its own file, and using:

```
typeset -i count=0
while read record
do
newfile="`echo $file`.$count.dat"
echo $record | sed 's/|~/\n/g' > $newfile
count=$count+1
done < $file
```

to put each record type on its own line within said file, but rolling it back up into one line with all possible fields present is quite tricky.  This is obviously not the best way since each file can have several thousand records, which would result in several thousand files, but I was using that as a starting point to get the logic down.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like a ghastly organization.  Are you sure you wouldn't do better with N files, one for each record type?

Comment: Is there documentary information somewhere for each record type and how many fields there need to be, and the sequence in which they appear?  Or can the sets of fields be in any order, so you could have ~EE, ~DD, ~CC, ~BB, ~AA in that sequence in a single line?  How will the script know which records should be present?  What should it do if it comes across a record which should not be present (so a ~FF in the example with 5 record types)?  If everything is sequenced, what should it do if it detects out of sequence data?

Comment: Please update the question with the extra information (and then delete those comments).  Two more questions: (1) If ~AA should always have 5 fields, what should happen if it comes across a record with only 4, or with 6 fields for an ~AA?  (2) Is there one of the record types that will always be present, or are they all optional?

Comment: Question has been updated.

Comment: Thanks for updating the question.  That's normal practice - the question needs to be as near self-contained as possible because comments are nominally 'transient'; they could be deleted, but the question should continue to be comprehensible and answerable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a executable awk script solution that isn't completely rigorous, but could get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="~" }

FNR==NR {
    dflts[$1] = create_empty_field($1,$2)
    if( $3 ~ /req|opt/ ) fld_order[++fld_cnt] = $1
    fld_rule[$1] = $3
    next
}

{
    flds = ""
    j = 1
    for(i=1; i<=fld_cnt; i++) {
        j = skip_flds( j )

        if($j !~ ("^" fld_order[i])) fld = dflts[fld_order[i]]
        else { fld = $j; j++ }
        flds = flds (flds=="" ? "" : OFS) fld
    }
    print flds
}

function create_empty_field(name, cnt,     fld, i) {
    fld = name
    for(i=1; i<=cnt; i++) { fld = fld "|" }
    return( fld )
}

function skip_flds(fnum,     name) {
    name = $fnum
    sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    while(fld_rule[name] == "skp") {
        fnum++
        name = $fnum
        sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    }
    return( fnum )
}
```

It takes an additional input file that specifies the defaults for each type of field, which I've called "known_flds"

```
AA~5~req
BB~2~opt
CC~3~opt
DD~6~opt
EE~4~opt
FF~2~skp
GG~4~opt
```

which has the same delimiter as the data file because I didn't want to add `FS` switching in either the script or between the input files.  It's an encoding of your field requirements.  The final field is shorthand for:

- req -> Mandatory ( in input or output or both? )
- opt -> Optional ( only optional in input )
- skp -> Skip ( in output )

When `awk.script` is made executable and run like `./awk.script known_flds data`, I get the following output:

```
AA|12345|ABCDE|67890|FGHIJ|~BB|12345|~CC|ABCDE|12345|~DD|A|B|C|D|E|~EE|1|2|3|~GG|F|R|T
AA|23456|BCDEF|78901|GHIJK|~BB||~CC|BCDEF|23456|~DD||||||~EE|2|3|4|~GG|R|F|G
AA|34567|CDEFG|89012|HIJKL|~BB||~CC|||~DD|B|C|D||~EE||||~GG||||
```

The `G` field in the questions data doesn't appear to either have the right number of fields specified or are missing a trailing pipe in the input data.

I made at least the following assumptions:

- Each field in the file is correct - the fields themselves don't need padding
- The fields are in the correct order, including fields that should be skipped.
- Any line might be missing the optional fields, and any missing, optional field should appear as an empty field in the output.
- The field order can be designated from the `known_flds` file.  Otherwise, I might have picked the first line of the file to be complete, in correct field order as well contain as all fields required for the output.  That wouldn't allow fields to be called mandatory though.

Here's a simple breakdown of the script:

- `FNR==NR` - parse in the original file and create default empty fields using the `create_empty_field()` function, putting the results in `dflts` by field name.  Create a basic field order, store it in `fld_order` array.  Skipped fields are not put into `fld_order`, but all field "rules" are added to the `fld_rule` array.
- All lines will be checked.  Check for fields order and only attempt to print out `fld_cnt` fields for any record.  Any fields past the line count in `known_flds` won't be output.
- For any record, skip `opt` fields and increment `j`.
- Build a `flds` variable with either the current field by `$j` or if it appears to be missing a field, with an empty field from `dflts`.
- Print out `flds` with the additional, empty fields but without skipped fields.

Here's a breakdown of the functions

`create_empty_field()`:

- `name, cnt` are arguments from the first file, while the `fld, i` are local variables set to empty values for using within the function.
- set `fld` to `name` ( `$1` from `known_flds` )
- Generate pipes up to `cnt` value ( `$2` from `known_flds` ).

`skip_flds()`:

- `fnum` is the argument for the record field number, while `name` is a local variable
- Pull the `name` part from `$fnum`
- Check to see if it should be skipped with `fld_rule[name] == "skp"` test.
- If it should be skipped, increment `fnum` and reset the `name` variable.
- I think the repeated `name =` and `sub` call lines should really be a new function, but I didn't do that here.

Basically, I'm making parsing/transformation rules in `known_flds` and then interpretting/enforcing them with `awk.script` against records in a `data` file.  While this is a reasonable start, you could additionally print errors to another file when manadatory fields are not present or would be empty, add missing subfields to fields, etc.  You could get as complicated as you like.

Comment: Definitely a great starting point, but I do have one question (and it may be a stupid one)...  Where did the `47` for `fld_cnt` come from?

Comment: Ok.  I get it now.  If I'm reading correctly, this does not include the removal of fields not in `known_flds` currently.  Correct?

Comment: I just discovered that the client is apparently adding fields to the end of each segment on the fly.  Based on my testing using the above logic, it appears that it is not forcing the number of fields to equal what is in the `known_flds` file if the record type is found (even though it appears as though it should be).  It just moves all fields between each `~` value.  Is there a way to force the number of fields too?

Comment: What do you mean by `client` (the awk script or the data file creator)?

Comment: Data file creator.  Our client who is delivering the file.

Comment: I changed the script and `known_flds` file to handle skipping fields.  If it doesn't work, then post some data that causes it to fail.

Comment: Using the updated script, it is not adding nor subtracting fields.

`AA|1234|ABCD|EDGFT|TR56BE|~BB||E5TGE|~CC|253641|84597|~DD|78HND|ACBE|||43|~EE|HISBL|78943|~FF|12345|SKIP|~GG|||TYBGFR`

With the script and the record above, using the same `known_flds` definitions, I was expecting:  

`AA|1234|ABCD|EDGFT|TR56BE|~BB||~CC|253641|84597|~DD|78HND|ACBE|||43|~EE|HISBL|78943||~GG|||TYBGFR`  

Instead, it returned:  

`AA|1234|ABCD|EDGFT|TR56BE|~BB||E5TGE|~CC|253641|84597|~DD|78HND|ACBE|||43|~EE|HISBL|78943|~GG|||TYBGFR`

Comment: The whole field `FF` field is stripped. You're correct when you say it doesn't add or remove subfields - that each field is well formed is one of the assumptions I stated. For example, `~BB||E5TGE|` field appears to have one too many subflds. You'd need to have rules about how to add/remove subfields from each field. It might be that all that's needed to modifiy `fld` is a function call, perhaps like `fld = fix_subflds( $j )` instead of `fld = $j, and logic in this new function `fix_subflds`. Though without more assumptions on my part, there's not enough info to determine how from the question

Comment: Based on your above statements, I was working under the assumption that your updated code was correcting the number of sub-fields.  My mistake.  I'll see what I can get working based off of the number of subfields being equal to what is in `known_flds`.  I'm not worried about the order of the subfields, just that is has the correct number of subfields.

Comment: My suggestion would be to use `cnt = split()` on the fields and add or removed subflds based on the `cnt` versus the second field from `known_flds` (which is currently not being stored).

Comment: There is obviously something I missed, probably in the call.  
  
I changed `else { fld = $j; j++ }` to `else { fld = fix_sub($j,$2); j++ }`  
  
I then added a new function:  
  
`function fix_sub(rec, num,  upd, cnt) {
cnt=split(rec,a,"|")-1
upd=""
if(cnt != num) 
{for(i=1;i<=$num;i++) 
upd = upd a[i] "|" }
else { upd=$rec }
return(upd)
}    `
  
Now I'm getting an `awk: 0602-562 Field $(BB||E5TGE|) is not correct.` error.  It's on the second set of subfields, so it's getting past the first AA without an issue.

Comment: `$2` is not a number in the `data` file.  You'd need to capture the info from the `$2` element in the `known_flds` file in a new array in the `FNR==NR` block and then lookup the `num` value - probably by field "name".  Since the comment section is getting long, please open a new [sscce styled question](http://sscce.org/) for further answers ( showing minimal inputs, code and expected output ).

Comment: Thanks @n0741337.  I've posted a new question with where everything is as now:  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30491496/4929856)