# awk Program File execution

Tags: unix, awk

As my last question was getting to long, here is a condensed version with the current code level.

Summary:  I need to take in a pipe-delimited input file, check to ensure all applicable record types are present, add any that are missing, and verify/correct the number of subfields within each record type.

Input records:

```
AA|1234|ABCD|EDGFT|TR56BE|~BB||E5TGE|~CC|253641|84597|~DD|78HND|ACBE|||43|~EE|HISBL|78943|~FF|12345|SKIP|~GG|||TYBGFR
AA|2345|CDEF|GFHIT|48UJKK|~CC||3FKTI
```

Record type and subfield count validation file `known_flds` entries:

```
AA~5~req
BB~2~opt
CC~3~opt
DD~6~opt
EE~4~opt
FF~2~skp
GG~4~opt
```

Current script, without the subfield correction:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="~" }

FNR==NR {
    dflts[$1] = create_empty_field($1,$2)
    if( $3 ~ /req|opt/ ) fld_order[++fld_cnt] = $1
    fld_rule[$1] = $3
    next
}

{
    flds = ""
    j = 1
    for(i=1; i<=fld_cnt; i++) {
        j = skip_flds( j )

        if($j !~ ("^" fld_order[i])) fld = dflts[fld_order[i]]
        else { fld = $j; j++ }
        flds = flds (flds=="" ? "" : OFS) fld
    }
    print flds
}

function create_empty_field(name, cnt,     fld, i) {
    fld = name
    for(i=1; i<=cnt; i++) { fld = fld "|" }
    return( fld )
}

function skip_flds(fnum,     name) {
    name = $fnum
    sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    while(fld_rule[name] == "skp") {
        fnum++
        name = $fnum
        sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    }
    return( fnum )
}
```

My initial attempt at performing the validation and correction of the subfields:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="~" }

FNR==NR {
    dflts[$1] = create_empty_field($1,$2)
    if( $3 ~ /req|opt/ ) fld_order[++fld_cnt] = $1
    fld_rule[$1] = $3
    next
}

{
    flds = ""
    j = 1
    for(i=1; i<=fld_cnt; i++) {
        j = skip_flds( j )
        if($j !~ ("^" fld_order[i])) fld = dflts[fld_order[i]]
        else { fld = fix_sub($j,$2); j++ }
        flds = flds (flds=="" ? "" : OFS) fld
    }
    print flds
}

function create_empty_field(name, cnt,     fld, i) {
    fld = name
    for(i=1; i<=cnt; i++) { fld = fld "|" }
    return( fld )
}

function skip_flds(fnum,     name) {
    name = $fnum
    sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    while(fld_rule[name] == "skp") {
        fnum++
        name = $fnum
        sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    }
    return( fnum )
}

function fix_sub(rec, num,  upd, cnt) {
    cnt=split(rec,a,"|")-1
    upd=""
    if(cnt != num) 
      {for(i=1;i<=$num;i++) 
       upd = upd a[i] "|" }
    else { upd=$rec }
    return(upd)
}
```

The above resulted in errors when it reached the second record type.  So now I know that I need to capture the 2nd value from the `known_flds` file in order to pass that through to the `fix_sub` function.

I will be adding:

```
        sub_fld[$1] = $2
```

In the `FNR==NR`section, but beyond that, my brain is simply fried and I cannot move forward.

I know as a standalone, the `fix_sub` area works.  Now I just need to get the value read from `known_flds` to pass through.

The desired output is:

```
AA|1234|ABCD|EDGFT|TR56BE|~BB||~CC|253641|84597|~DD|78HND|ACBE|||43|~EE|HISBL|78943||~GG|||TYBGFR
AA|2345|CDEF|GFHIT|48UJKK|~BB||~CC||3FKTI|~DD||||||~EE||||~GG|||
```

Original question:  [UNIX Shell Script Solution for formatting a pipe-delimited, segmented file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30402228/1259917)

Comment: If records are separated by `~` and fields are separated by `|` in the input file then you should probably tell `awk` to do that too (i.e. `RS="~" FS="|"`). Then you get a more natural operation on records and fields. Since that's only true for the input (not the field file) you can set those on the command line like this `awk '<script>' FS='~' field_file RS='~' FS='|' input_file` and it will work the way you want.

Comment: Ah, that may not work that easily if you really do need to split the input by line also... but you might still want to use that idea and use `split()` on `|` after you've split into `~`-delimited fields.

Comment: Record types are separated by `~`, but it is still would need to be read as all one record (for use by sqlldr later).  The true record separator would be `RS = '\n'`.

Comment: Where did `E5TGE` in the `~BB` entry go on the first line? Does the tag field (e.g. `~BB` count towards the field count (i.e. `|~BB||~CC` is two `~BB` fields)?

Comment: @EtanReisner:  Yes, the record type identifier does count in field count.  The end result of this is to be utilized by a `sqlldr`, so all fields must be accounted for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this modified script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS=OFS="~" }

FNR==NR {
    dflts[$1] = create_empty_field($1,$2)
    if( $3 ~ /req|opt/ ) {
        fld_order[++fld_cnt] = $1
        subfld_cnt[$1] = $2
    }
    fld_rule[$1] = $3
    next
}

{
    flds = ""
    j = 1
    for(i=1; i<=fld_cnt; i++) {
        j = skip_flds( j )
        if($j !~ ("^" fld_order[i])) fld = dflts[fld_order[i]]
        else { fld = fix_sub(j); j++ }
        flds = flds (flds=="" ? "" : OFS) fld
    }
    print flds
}

function get_field_name(fnum,      name) {
    name = $fnum
    sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    return( name )
}

function create_empty_field(name, cnt,     fld, i) {
    fld = name
    for(i=1; i<=cnt; i++) { fld = fld "|" }
    return( fld )
}

function skip_flds(fnum,     name) {
    name = get_field_name(fnum)
    while(fld_rule[name] == "skp") {
        fnum++
        name = $fnum
        sub(/\|.*$/, "", name)
    }
    return( fnum )
}

function fix_sub(fnum,       name, cnt, a, scnt, i, upd) {
    name = get_field_name(fnum)
    cnt = split($fnum, a, "|")-1
    scnt = subfld_cnt[ name ]
    if(cnt != scnt) {
        for(i=1;i<=scnt;i++)
            upd = upd a[i] "|"
        return( upd )
    }
    return( $fnum )
}
```

The key differences:

- `subfld_cnt[$1] = $2` has been added to the `req|opt` section in the `FNR==NR` block ( handling the `known_flds` file )
- Added `get_field_name()` function which returns the first subfield of the field specified by its `fnum` argument.
- Called `get_field_name()` from function `skip_flds()`
- Modified `fix_sub()` to take only the `fnum` ( all the other variables are local to the function ) and fix the number of subfield pipes if necessary.  Now the call to it only takes a `j` argument as in `fix_sub(j)`.

Breakdown of `fix_sub()` changes:

- `name = get_field_name(fnum)` to get the field name for lookup
- `split` the `$fnum`, and get the count of split (leaving in your -1 adjustment)
- `scnt = subfld_cnt[ name ]` to get the desired field count from the array that was added to the processing of the `known_flds` file.  This is primary piece you were missing.
- When `cnt != scnt` fix the subflds.
- Left in your `upd` setting code, but removed the `upd = ""` - that's already done for local variables.
- Personal preference - return directly with either value instead of the `else`.

I get the following:

```
AA|1234|ABCD|EDGFT|TR56BE|~BB||~CC|253641|84597|~DD|78HND|ACBE|||43|~EE|HISBL|78943
||~GG|||TYBGFR|
AA|2345|CDEF|GFHIT|48UJKK|~BB||~CC||3FKTI|~DD||||||~EE||||~GG||||
```

which doesn't exactly match your desired output.  The difference is in the final `|` in the `GG` field.  I think your desired output is missing it.  Otherwise, the final pipe of the final field just needs to be dropped after all other processing.

Comment: that works beautifully!  Thank you again for all your help in solving this tricky situation.  I can handle the final `|`.  I mainly did not want it there because even though `sqlldr` won't read it as a final column if it's not specified in the control file, others who might need to handle this issue down the road might.